# Short code to get 2 values from one row with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

Possibly stupid question, but can not find answer.

I need to get values from two columns of the same row.

And then set variables with each value.

Here I get one value from column Number and then define variable $NumberPostRegister1

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Number FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1");
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1);
$stmt->execute();
$NumberPostRegister1 = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $NumberPostRegister1 .' NumberPostRegister1<br>';
```

Here I get second value from column IfDraft and then define variable $IfDraft1

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT IfDraft FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1");
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1);
$stmt->execute();
$IfDraft1 = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $IfDraft1 .' NumberPostRegister1<br>';
```

Two queries and rather long code.

How to do the same using one query and shorter/simpler code?

Comment: Why not select both columns in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT IfDraft, Number FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($row_id1));
list($IfDraft, $Numer) = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Number, IfDraft FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1");
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1);
$stmt->execute();
list($NumberPostRegister1, $IfDraft1) = $stmt->fetch();